# Tomcat7 Java Servlet Crashes after a few minutes

Tags: java, eclipse, servlets, crash, tomcat7

I have a java servlet running on a tomcat7 web server.  I've written a program that loads a page from the server every 10 seconds.  The page is called up with a PHP script that uses the CURL function to trigger Tomcat to serve up the web page  The page is very simple and takes less than 1 second to load.

After about 5 minutes or so, the server crashes. Checking my log files, I get inconsistent errors as to why.

Frequently I received `java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file` as the error right before the site crashes.  Most recently I received a `null pointer exception` before the crash.  These error resulted form the same initial conditions (I simply restarted Tomcat between crashes and did not alter any code)

I used Eclipse to build my servlet.  I'm new to Tomcat and I'd like to fix it so that it is stable.  Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

I'm using tomcat 7, and my java version is:

```
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_26-b03)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.1-b02, mixed mode)
```

Stack Trace (#### is for removed content):

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [##################] in context with path [/##################] threw exception
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.loadResource(Configuration.java:1387)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.loadResources(Configuration.java:1251)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getProps(Configuration.java:1192)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.get(Configuration.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration.checkDefaultsVersion(HBaseConfiguration.java:63)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration.addHbaseResources(HBaseConfiguration.java:89)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration.create(HBaseConfiguration.java:100)
    ########################
    ###########################
    #########################
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:928)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:987)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:539)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:298)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:127)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:135)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:72)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.<init>(URLJarFile.java:72)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.getJarFile(URLJarFile.java:48)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarFileFactory.get(JarFileFactory.java:70)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.connect(JarURLConnection.java:104)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.getInputStream(JarURLConnection.java:132)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:653)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLVersionDetector.determineDocVersion(XMLVersionDetector.java:186)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:772)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:737)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:119)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:235)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:284)
    at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(DocumentBuilder.java:180)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.loadResource(Configuration.java:1300)
```

Comment: I bet a hardware problem. A broken CPU transitor, a broken RAM cell, a broken harddisk sector, etc. Run some diagnostic/stress/benchmark programs to exclude one and other. If necessary try a different machine.

Comment: @BalusC My computer is in a cloud environment (Ubuntu OS), so I don't think it's a hardware error.  I'm guessing it's either a configuration error, something with the classpath, or something coded improperly in the servlet itself

Comment: Well.. I'd still try a different machine first. A simple but healthy laptop or something. Use exactly the same JRE/JDK and Tomcat version and WAR file. Edit: wait, you said Ubuntu? What JRE/JDK vendor are you using? The GCJ which I believe ships by default in some Ubuntu versions has really serious bugs. If you're indeed using it, replace by Sun/Oracle one and retry.

Comment: Ok I just tried it. The servers weren't exact replicas, but they had the same OS.  I used eclipse to instal tomcat on one installation, and on the other server I manually installed tomcat.  Same results

Comment: can you put the stack traces of different errors that your getting?

Comment: Okay. Can you tell the JRE/JDK make/version? And Tomcat version? And indeed, the complete stacktrace of such a `ZipException` may also be helpful.

Comment: I've run into situations where interfacing with zip/unzip just fails for no reason. Is your servlet reading a config file every time its invoked? If so, try doing it once at startup.

Comment: @Bill can you explain briefly how to load a config file upon start up or point me to a tutorial describing how  it's done?

Comment: This is definitely OS platform related. I'm not sure what Hadoop does, but doesn't it do something with disk storage? Is there any chance that there are just too many open files and thus simply no more files can be opened? (that it's a ZIP file is just pure coincidence, Java is one and all JARs which are all ZIP files anyway).

Comment: The easiest way would be to have a static member in your servlet that holds the configuration, and then initialize that static member with a static function call that reads the configuration and returns it. Then reference that config in your service methods. Statics can get you in trouble when you want to reload servlets though, so its not the best way, but its enough for you to test and see if it makes a difference. The 'right' way is probably with some sort of JEE dependency injection.

Comment: @BalusC   I saw hints on my own web research that it might be too many files that are open, and adjusting the ulim would fix that.  If If that is the problem and increase the ulim, do you think the problem would go away or just reoccur after a longer period of time?

Comment: Well, stress testing should prove that. You could use for example JMeter for this. It's a somewhat spartan program, but it does its job.

Comment: AH!  i changed the ulim, and rebooted the server.  now when I log in I am automatically logged out, so the server is dead to me.  I set the ulim to 'USERNAME - nofile 32768'.  I think I might have to rebuild the server unless anyone knows a workaround, which i guess is a subject for another post... :-(

Comment: dont know how it is on the cloud, but typically such errors are because your /var or /tmp or /root directories are full (no swap space, or no space for the OS to operate). the zip error sounds like either a corrupt JAR or lack of space to extract contents. obviously, all of this is more of a guess work :-)

Comment: @Tucker the code you wrote would be helpful. Without it just from the stack trace my wild guess would be that you are initializing hadoop within the service method of the servlet. So that would get done on each call to the servlet, i.e. each curl from your php page. If you aren't handling the hadoop lifecycle properly in your servlet, you can handily have an issue.  See http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/GenericServlet.html#init() for help on init in a servlet. See http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html for what is probably a better way.